# Function Registry + Polymorphism?

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism

I have a series of structures that all inherit from a base struct, and I also have a series of functions that take in a different child struct as an input.

I am trying to create a simple function registry/map using the various functions created. I assumed I would be able to use the base struct for the mapping of the functions, but when I go to insert the functions into the map I run into the error:

`error: no matching member function for call to 'insert' registry.insert({"func1", func1});`

Here is the code I have written at the moment:

```
// Standard Includes
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Base
{
};

struct Test1 : Base
{
};

struct Test2: Base
{
};

inline bool func1(Test1 x)
{
    return true;
}

inline bool func2(Test2 x)
{
    return false;
}

using func = std::function<bool(Base)>;

inline std::unordered_map<std::string, func> functionRegistry()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, func> registry;

    registry.insert({"func1", func1});
    registry.insert({"func2", func2});

    return registry;
}
```

I would appreciate any help here if this is even possible (I assume it is, I am probably just doing something silly)!

Comment: Research object slicing.

Answer (score 3):

The code you show doesn't use any kind of polymorphism.

With that said, you can solve your problem by passing the arguments by *reference* instead of by value. Then insert *lambdas* into the map, which calls the actual functions using a suitable downcast:

```
bool func1(Test1& x)
{
    return true;
}

bool func2(Test2& x)
{
    return false;
}

using func = std::function<bool(Base&)>;

std::unordered_map<std::string, func> functionRegistry()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, func> registry;

    registry.insert({"func1", [](Base& x) { return func1(static_cast<Test1&>(x)); }});
    registry.insert({"func2", [](Base& x) { return func2(static_cast<Test2&>(x)); }});

    return registry;
}
```

---

Note that I removed the `inline` specifier. Besides changing the linkage of the function, it's merely a *suggestion* to the compiler. The compiler will, or will not, inline the functions as it seems fit.

Comment: That looks like it worked, Thank you! Also I thought having the structures inherit from a base/parent structure was a form of polymorphism -- I guess I was wrong. Thank you for all the insight here, regardless, I appreciate it

Comment: Downcasting can be tricky better to make Base a pure virtual baseclass (with pure virtual getters/setters/functions) too. Then no casting is needed in your lambda functions at all